# Почему источник света создает неизвестные цвета ночью?

Tags: unity3d

Я решил создать простенькую игру, и решил добавить скрипт на вращение главного источника света. Когда солнце уходит за горизонт и скайбокс становиться черным, на 2-3 секунды появляются фиолетово-зелёные цвета, так и еще очень яркие, что аж глаза болят.
Вот и сам вопрос, откуда появляеться такой свет?

Скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SunRotating : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 0.05f;

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, Speed,0));
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]